# Why complete function is never called in my code

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I was learning Observables and trying out little things. Everything is working properly except 'observer.complete()' which is not invoking 'complete' method in subscription.

I searched the internet but didn't managed to solve my problem. I also want to know how to write function that is invoked by unsubscribing from an observable. Thanks in advance.

```
let observable = new Observable<string>((observer) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next('new1');
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next('new2');
  }, 3000)
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.complete()
  }, 6000)

  }).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data),
    (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    },
    ()=>{
      console.log('completed')
    }


})
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you wrote only `next` callback

```
.subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data)
    }, <=============================================== note } here
    (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    },
    ()=>{
      console.log('completed')
    }
)
```

or simply

```
.subscribe(
  console.log,
  (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  },
  () => {
    console.log('completed')
  }
)
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/O7jHM7PAhAX4Iin99y05)**

Comment: your awesome. I was finding the root cause and I didn't notice the `}`. Would like to connect with you too :)